# show() is not working in Firefox, but works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css

So I have been scratching my head for an hour, trying different solutions, searching around this website and the Internet, I don't understand why it doesnt work ...
I created a very simple mailbox for my website. When the user enters the name of another user, an ajax request is sent to verify if the username exists or not. According to the answer, a small icon with a text appears to inform the user that the username exists (or not) and enables a Send button if the username is correct.
This code works fine in Chrome, but I cannot make it work in Firefox. Here it is :

```js
$.ajax(
{
 type: 'POST',  
 url: "ajax.php",
 data: { 'user_nick': nick },
 success: function(answer)  
 {
  if(isNaN(answer))
  {
   $("#user-not-found").show();
   $("#send-msg").attr("disabled", true).css("opacity", "0.5");
  }
  else // returns user id if username exists
  {
   $("#user-found").show();
   $("input[name=sendto_id]").val(answer);
   $("#send-msg").attr("disabled", false).css("opacity", "1");
  }
 },
 error: function(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message)
 {
  alert('An error has occured, please try again later (status-> '+textstatus+')');
  populateBugForm(location.href, textstatus, message);
 }
});
```

```html
<p style="height:35px;margin-top:0px;">
<span class="email-display-field">To : </span>
<input id="sendto" type="text" size="25">
<span id="user-not-found" style="display:none;z-index:30;margin-left:10px;">
<span id="user-found" style="display:none;margin-left:10px;">
```

The jquery function is triggered by a blur event on #sendto.
$("#user-found").show() and $("#send-msg").attr("disabled", false).css("opacity", "1") do not work (as well as $("#user-found").show()), but the funny part is that the id is correctly inserted in $("input[name=sendto_id]").val(answer).

No idea what to do ...

Thank you !

Comment: Um...how is your snippet supposed to work without a backend?!

Comment: Also, when is this Ajax event fired?

Answer (score 0):

Basically is the ALT method that is not working. Please, could you try this:

```
$.ajax(
    {
    type: 'POST',  
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: { 'user_nick': nick },
    success: function(answer)  
    {
        if(isNaN(answer))
        {
            $("#user-not-found").show();
            $("#send-msg").prop("disabled", true).css("opacity", "0.5");
        }
        else // returns user id if username exists
        {
            $("#user-found").show();
            $("input[name=sendto_id]").val(answer);
            $("#send-msg").prop("disabled", false).css("opacity", "1");
        }
    },
    error: function(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message)
    {
        alert('An error has occured, please try again later (status-> '+textstatus+')');
        populateBugForm(location.href, textstatus, message);
    }
});
```